# Autentication and authorization in angularjs when consuming multiple REST-backends

Tags: angularjs, rest, authentication, jersey, authorization

**Scenario:**

- Multiple REST-backends, for ex. developed using Jersey, and deployed separately, say in jetty-containers.
- Single, and separately deployed AngularJS web app consuming each of those REST-backends.

Now, what I want is add authentication and authorization so that a user can login using an html-form.

Now, the only thing I am sure of is that I do not need OAuth, because no thirdparty needs to access the REST-backends, but only the AngularJS app.

I have looked into Apache Shiro, Spring Security, and other frameworks, but I don't understnad how to consolidate the frontend and backends in terms of authentication and authorization.

Does any of you guys has any example of how to do it without cluttering my code with security specific aspects?

**Possible/Plausible solution?**

If I implement and deploy a separate and very thin REST-service just for authentication and authorization, say with the POST endpoint `https://.../authenticate`, which returns either an error message or a JSON response with details about the user, along with a unique session token, then I can include this token and other neccessary headers within each subsequent request/response. Each REST-backend can then filter each request and check whether the given header information, using session token and role etc., is authenticated and authorized.

Are there any drawbacks/flaws to this solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a authentication and authorization and not oAuth then go for "Basic Authentication" with Angular.

Example of implementation is shown in below link:
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/05/26/AngularJS-Basic-HTTP-Authentication-Example.aspx

Comment: Just read the link you posted. Good example, but I don't think it solve the problem in this question; I have multiple rest-backends, and I need to CONSOLIDATE the frontend with all those backends in terms of authentication and authorization.

Answer (score 0):

If all your backends require the same authentication credentials for Basic Authentication, then you can set the default header value for Authentication header so that it will be used for all your `http` requests.

```js
var authdata = btoa($scope.user.email + ':' + $scope.user.password);

$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + authdata; // set default Authorization header value.

//Call multiple backends now. The Authorization header will remain unless it is explicitly cleared.
```

Comment: Could work, but I don't really want to use Basic Auth, and resend username/password each time.